# Form / Form_Container not finding each other

Tags: adminform

***Disclaimer:*** I know there are hundreds of thousands of questions about this already on the internet, but I just cannot find the solution to my problem. Maybe I'm overlooking something.

---

I have a working admin page with a `Form_Container`. If I'm not mistaken, it should find the form (its child) on its own, given the right parameters. However, there is no form child element and the site gives me an error telling me something along these lines.

Here's the container:

```
class Adornis_TPS_Block_Adminhtml_Tradeplace_Product_Get extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->_objectId = 'get';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'adornis_tps_adminhtml';
    $this->_controller = 'tradeplace_product';
    $this->_mode = 'edit';

    $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('adornis_tps')->__('Get Data'));
    $this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('*/*/save')."')");
}
}
```

And here's the form:

```
<?php

class Adornis_TPS_Block_Adminhtml_Tradeplace_Product_Get_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

public function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('ean' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('ean'))),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('ean_input', array(
        'legend' => Mage::helper('adornis_tps')->__('EAN Input'),
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('adornis_tps')->__('EAN'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        'required' => true,
        'name' => 'ean'
    ));

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
```

And finally, here is the relevant section from the `config.xml` (`<global><blocks/></global>`)

```
        <adornis_tps_adminhtml>
            <class>Adornis_TPS_Block_Adminhtml</class>
        </adornis_tps_adminhtml>
```

---

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the controller (`TpsController.php`):

```
<?php

class Adornis_TPS_Adminhtml_TpsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

public function indexAction() {...}

public function getAction() {
    $templateBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adornis_tps_adminhtml/tradeplace_product_get');
    $this->loadLayout()->_addContent($templateBlock)->renderLayout();
}

public function saveAction() {
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    //echo $this->getRequest()->getParams('ean');
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have the proper admin controller and admin layout files setup for this page ? If so can you post them too.

Comment: @DigitalPianism see my edit please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this problem all the time. The best way to debug the issue it to edit `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container::_prepareLayout` to add in some debug code:

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    if ($this->_blockGroup && $this->_controller && $this->_mode) {
        Mage::log('Looking for block: ' . $this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form');
        $this->setChild('form', $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_blockGroup . '/' . $this->_controller . '_' . $this->_mode . '_form'));
    }
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

Then check your logs, it normally becomes pretty obvious why it isn't finding the block. **Don't forget to remove the change afterwards**.

In your case it's because you have the form as `Adornis_TPS_Block_Adminhtml_Tradeplace_Product_Get_Form` whereas it's looking for the class `Adornis_TPS_Block_Adminhtml_Tradeplace_Product_Edit_Form`.

**Edit:** There are two viable ways to fix this:

1. Rename your class to match what it's attempting to load.
2. Change the value of `_mode`.

**NB: Whilst changing `_mode` shouldn't cause you any drama, the `_controller` property is used for more than just the form name and changing it will also affect the default form action, and the css class applied to the header.**

Comment: thanks :) correct answer, if you add that you can avoid this by changing `_mode` from `edit` to `get` in this case, I'll even upvote it ;)

Comment: Updated to add the 2 viable fixes, and a minor note about changing the other properties.

Comment: maaaaaaan I wish there was a documentation where you could find things like these. Without Stackexchange I would be pretty darn lost with Magento since I'm pretty green... You got an upvote of course, thanks for the quality answer again!